# Get "first" AND "last" character of a php string in one line?

Tags: php

Is there a one line way to combine getting first and last character of a string?

I tried (without success):

```
$title = "IncredibleTitle";
$title_characters = (mb_substr($title, 0, 1, 'UTF8')) && (mb_substr($title, 0, -1, 'UTF8'));
```

Comment: Nope, that link doesnt work, because its not a "one line" solution.

Comment: Don't use && to concatenate strings.

Comment: Yes, I see, but . ' ' . also doesnt work ;(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `.` period character for concatenation.
- To get last character, 2nd param has to be -1 and third param will be value 1 or the length. See [`mb_substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php).

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$title = "IncredibleTitle";
$title_characters = (mb_substr($title, 0, 1, 'UTF8')) . (mb_substr($title, -1, 1, 'UTF8'));
echo $title_characters;
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/acd96)